# Separated salary from per annum and per day

Tags: python, eda

I have csv file 
salary = pd.read_csv('./datasets/salary.csv')

[image]

is it possible to have an output like this

[image]

Comment: In line 0 you have "12000 to 140000" and you want that to be interpreted as /per annum/. In line 6 you have "600-700" and want that to be interpreted as daily. How is your program going to decide that one is /per annum/ and one is daily? Are you going to decide an upper limit on day rates? That seems risky.

Comment: we can get the length of the 1st salary let say 120000. if length equal 5 or 6 then per annum else if length 2 to 4 equal to per day. is that possible?

Answer (score 0):

*Apology for sharing only the concept as you did not provide any code in the question. Consider adding example code if you are unable to understand the concept.*

This will require creating a new "column" - "Label" in the dataframe for each matching *"Salary"*. For example, check the table in the link below:

### [Click to see a sample table to achieve desired columns](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5bbcA.png)

This columns *"Label"* can be filled using ifesle statements. Use string function or == "string in the column Salary" to write the conditional statements. Additionally, use for loop if dataframe has multiple entries for each type of salary. Second, create the three new columns of interest i.e. *"per annum", "p.a. + Super", and "p.d."*. Now, use ifesle statement again on Label column to enter values row wise in each column of interest based on the conditional statement. 
This should let you achieve the desired entries. 
Hope it helps.